# how to select "###dog" from the dropdown list?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

```
<select name="dropdown" multiple="multiple" size="2">

  <option value="1">#Ram</option>
  <option value="2">##animals</option>
  <option value="3">###cat</option>
  <option value="4">###dog</option>
  <option value="5">#kalu</option>
  <option value="6">##animals</option>
  <option value="7">###rat</option>
  <option value="8">###dog</option>
  <option value="9">#jadu</option>
  <option value="10">##animals</option>
  <option value="11">###cat</option>

</select>
```

Now I want to select `###dog`, which comes after #kalu->##animals->###dog - it is the input I would give. But now
point is how to select the correct `###dog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to get all of the options and determine the path (ie parents) of each option.

The following would work for your html sample. Hopefully I have not made too many assumptions.

```
#This is the option (path) you want to select
option_to_select = '#kalu->##animals->###dog'

#Get the select list
dropdown = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(driver.find_element(:name => 'dropdown'))

#Get the text of all options
option_text = dropdown.options.collect(&:text)

#For each option, determine its full path and value
paths = {}
option_text.each_with_index do |text, index|
    level = text[/^(#+)/].length
    segment = option_text[0..index]
    path = []
    1.upto(level) do |i|
        path << segment[segment.rindex{ |x| x =~ /^#{'#' * i}\w/ }]
    end
    paths[path.join('->')] = (index + 1).to_s
end

#Convert the desired option path to a value and select it from the dropdown
dropdown.select_by(:value, paths[option_to_select])
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and I will definately give it a try. Thanks Justin as usual. It seems you always have the answers of each problem, I ever have seen :)

Answer (score 0):

Sizzle must support CSS selectors:

```rb
driver.find_element(:css, "select option:contains('###dog'):last")
```

Comment: I didn't get your point. Could you clarify it? I want a generic soltuion for that.